# Remove tag synonym [playframework-2.x] -> [playframework-2.0]

Tags: support, stack-overflow, tags, retag-request, tag-synonyms

There are now some questions about [playframework-2.1](/questions/tagged/playframework-2.1). When I try to tag these questions with [playframework-2.x](/questions/tagged/playframework-2.x), SO adds the tag [playframework-2.0](/questions/tagged/playframework-2.0) instead, which is of course wrong. Can someone please fix that?

Comment: Additionally, could [tag:playframework-2.0] be delinked from [tag:playframework-2.1]? Makes sense.

Comment: Why would we like to maintain 2.0 and 2.1? 1.x and 2.x makes more sense to me? Because those two versions are the active ones.